# Letting bash know to search for a corresponding floating number when given an integer

Tags: bash, type-conversion

I use a CFD code to run a simulation. Output files are written into a folder with the time stamp as its name. If the time is greater than 1e6, the folder name is printed in a floating point format.  Like ..., 993600, 997200, 1.0008e+06, 1.0044e+06, 1.008e+06, ... and so on.

I need to extract some data from these output files. I wrote a bash script and it works well if the output time of folder is less than 1e6. After that when floder names are greater than 1e6, the bash file keeps reading the numbers in integer format whereas my files are in floating point format and therefore reports an error (file not found error) due to mismatch.

For example, bash looks for the folder 1000800 whereas I have the folder 1.0008e+06. Is there a way to tell bash what you are looking for is in a floating format to finish the job?

Any pointers please?

Answer (score 0):

After several trials, I found a non-elegant way to do this.
I create a string variable:

time="1.008e+06"

to look for the specific folder name and get into it to run few commands.

A drawback using this procedure is that it becomes cumbersome if there are many folders as I need to explicitly enter the folder name in the bash script and looping through is not possible this way.